# unable to return data from controller to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, phalcon

I'm using phalcon framework and In my blog i want to append comments with ajax but the problem is in my controller query. i don't understand how to return query data to view with ajax. my current query script return entire hole html page but i need only commented data. someone please help

**[Controller]**

```
public function detailsAction($id)
{
    $blog = Blogs::findFirstByid($id);

#Comments Retrieve
    $coment = Comments::find();
}

public function bCommentAction()
{
    if($this->session->has('uname'))
    {
        if($this->request->isPost() == true || $this->request->isAjax() == true) 
        {
            $comments = new Comments();
            $comments->cauthor = trim($this->session->get('uname'));
            $comments->bcoment = trim($this->request->getPost('bComent'));
            $comments->entry_id = trim($this->request->getPost('postId'));
            if(!$comments->create() == true)
            {
                $this->flashSession->success("SUCCESS:: Comments inserted");
                return $this->response->redirect($this->request->getHTTPReferer());
            }
            else
            {
    return $this->response->setJsonContent(['bcoment' => $comments->bcoment, 
    'cauthor' => $comments->cauthor, 'entry_id' => $comments->entry_id]);
            }
        }
        else{echo('Request is Not ajax!');}
    }
    else
    {
        echo('<script>alert("You are not loggedin!");</script>');
    }
    $this->view->disabled();
}
```

**[Jquery]**

```
$('#blogComment').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var blogComent = $("input[name='bComent']").val();
    var postsId = $("input[name='idPost']").val();
    $.ajax({
        url:'blog/bComment/',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: {'postId':postsId,'bComent':blogComent},
        success: function(data){ 
            $('#datax').append('<div class="bcom">'+json.stringify(data)+'</div>').fadeIn(500);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

**[View]**

```
<div id="datax">
{% for coment in comented %}
{% if coment.entry_id === detail.id %}
<div class="bcom">
{% for user in logged %}
{% if coment.cauthor === user.uname %}
{{ image('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=',"alt": "Some Photo","data-src":"uploads/users/"~user.image,"title":""~user.uname,"class":"comentedId") }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
<b>{{coment.cauthor}}</b><br/>
{{coment.bcoment}}
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}</div>
```

Output looks like image below:

[image]

Comment: Can you update your question with the current HTML markup? And the desired result, please?

Comment: Just check what is data returned in success callback. Not sure what happens here exactly. Are you sure data is object in this callback?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving this line to the top of your action.:

```
$this->view->disabled();
```

By the looks of it with your current code, it never gets fired.

Also, I would consider rewriting this block:

```
    if(!$comments->create() == true)
    {
        $this->flashSession->success("SUCCESS:: Comments inserted");
        return $this->response->redirect($this->request->getHTTPReferer());
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->response->setJsonContent(['bcoment' => $comments->bcoment, 'cauthor' => $comments->cauthor, 'entry_id' => $comments->entry_id]);
    }
```

Perhaps something as simple as:

```
if(!$comments->create()){
    return $this->response->setJsonContent(['status' => 'error']);
) else {
    return $this->response->setJsonContent([
        'status' => 'success',
        'payload' => [
            'bcoment' => $comments->bcoment, 
            'cauthor' => $comments->cauthor, 
            'entry_id' => $comments->entry_id
        ]
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like This :

```
$('#comentSave').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var coment = $('.comnt').val();
    var cid = $('.pid').val();
    $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'blog/comments',
    data:{'bcoment':coment,'postId':cid},
    beforeSend: function(){$('.loader').html('Processing...');}
    }).done(function(resp){
        console.log(typeof resp);
        resp = JSON.parse(resp);
        resp.forEach(function(value){
            if(value.e === 'e1'){alert('Insertion Failed!');}
            if(value.e === 'e2'){alert('You are not authorized!');}
            if(value.e === 'e3'){if(value.uname === value.cauthor){var cdata = 'bcomBase';}else{cdata = 'bcom';}
                $('#datax').append('<div class="'+cdata+'"><img src="uploads/users/'+value.userimg+'"><b>'+value.cauthor+'</b><br/>'+value.bcoment+'</div>');
                $('.comentcount').text(value.count);
            }
        });
        $('#blogComment')[0].reset() || $('.comnt').val('');
    }).fail(function(){ alert('Reload & try again..!'); }).always(function(){});
    return false;
});


public function commentsAction()
{
$this->view->disable();
if(!empty($this->session->get('uname')))
{
    $comments = new Comments();
    $comments->cauthor = $this->session->get('uname');
    $comments->bcoment = $this->request->getPost('bcoment');
    $comments->entry_id = $this->request->getPost('postId');
    $resData = array();
    if($comments->save() === true)
    {
        $data = Blogs::findFirstByid($this->request->getPost('postId'));
        $cc = Comments::countByentry_id($this->request->getPost('postId'));
        $user = Users::findFirstByid($this->session->get('id'));
        $query = Comments::findByid($comments->id);
        foreach($query as $q){$resData[] = array('bcoment' => $q->bcoment, 'cauthor' => $q->cauthor, 'entry_id' => $q->entry_id, 'count' => $cc, 'userimg' => $user->image, 'e' => 'e3', 'uname' => $data->blog_author);}
        echo(json_encode($resData));                
    }
    else{$resData[] = array('e' => 'e1');echo(json_encode($resData));}
}
else{$resData[] = array('e' => 'e2');echo(json_encode($resData));}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get only the text of the comment and do an "echo" of it as a json file. Do a research about returning json from the server. There's a lot of references on the internet about how to parse an php array to json string and retrieving this for the ajax request.

And, you'll have to change your javascript's ajax request too, in order to take that json string and parse it to an javascript array.

Comment: Could u please give a example?

Comment: I understood what you were doing.
Instead of redirecting here: return $this->response->redirect($this->request->getHTTPReferer());
You have to just show the data. can you show the method "$comments->create()"?

Comment: Inside your php script, you must return your json string containing the data. I will find an example.

Comment: If i do like: return json_encode($comments); then output like below: [object object] instantly after refresh hole page it shows real data

Comment: Like this:

You do your mysql query... and then you have an array that will look like this, i presume: $row = ("username"=> "John", "content"=>"This is my comment").

Just do:

header('Content-type: application/json');

echo json_encode($row);

Comment: show us what is inside the method: 'response' and 'create'

Comment: its make my page blank

Comment: If i make my php query like return json_encode($comments); and in jquery make it like $('#datax').append('<div class="bcom">'+JSON.stringify(data)+'</div>').fadeIn(500); then out put like: {"id":"56","cauthor":"webmaster"}

Comment: take the context of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php?rq=1

I think you want do something like this. Return data parsed from the database. It seems like the current structure of your application will not allow you to return json data properly.

Comment: this is the json file returned by the server: {"id":"56","cauthor":"webmaster"}. You have to parse it to an array.

Comment: again, show your methods, so i can see what's going on inside your program

Comment: Not understand response & create

Comment: you may want to watch console.log output when jquery response

Comment: $comments->create() and $this->response

Comment: could u please come to teamviewer? pls

Comment: response: {"id":"76","cauthor":"webmaster","bcoment":"Phalcon post","entry_id":"2"}